# Compilation Issues

Tags: java, compilation

I wrote the following code for Pascal's triangle on https://leetcode.com/ and I got the error as follows:

> Line 10: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to
>   `List<List<Integer>>`.

```
    public class Solution {
        public List<List<Integer>> generate(int numRows) {
        List list;
        int  temp;
        for(int i=0;i<numRows;i++) {
            temp = (int) Math.pow(11,i);
            list.add(Arrays.asList(temp));

        }
        return temp;
    }
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner();
        System.out.println("Enter the no.of Rows");
        int numRows = scan.nextInt();
        solution.generate(numRows);
    }
}
```

Help me to find the solution.

Comment: your method returns a `List` but youre trying to return an `int`...

Comment: It's not clear why you're using a raw type for `list` - I'd try to avoid that to start with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost right answer. Just few mistypes. Here is good one:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Solution {
    public List<Integer> generate(int numRows) {
        List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int temp;
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            temp = (int) Math.pow(11, i);
            list.add(temp);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the no.of Rows");
        int numRows = scan.nextInt();
        Object answer=solution.generate(numRows);
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Alex!

Answer (score 1):

```
 public List<Integer> generate(int numRows) {
    List list;
    int  temp;
    for(int i=0;i<numRows;i++) {
        temp = (int) Math.pow(11,i);
        list.add(Arrays.asList(temp));

    }
    return list;
```

Why are returning `int` value for `List` return type. please change it to list. It will compile properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is defined as returning a `List<List<Integer>>` (a list of lists of integers) but you are trying to return an integer.

You have created the `List` in the method, so you should return that, and not the integer `temp`.